# Passing a map location variable to other view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I was able to get the location using CLLocationManager() and the city information is able to display in the Text(config.text). Can someone help how to pass that "config.text" to other view (mainView())

struct CityLocationView2 : View {
let location: Location

```
@State var config = CityLocationView2Config()

var body: some View {
    
 Text(config.text)
    
    mainView().   // How to pass the city ????? 
        .task(id: location.id) {
            await config.reverseGecode(location: location)
        }
}
```

}

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
struct CityLocationView2 : View {
    let location: Location
    @State var config = CityLocationView2Config()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(config.text)
        MainView(text: config.text)   // <-- here
            .task(id: location.id) {
                await config.reverseGecode(location: location)
            }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State var text: String  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
    }
}
```

You can of course also use `let text: String` or `var text: String`, etc...

I recommend you read and do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/
Knowing how to pass values to other Views is essential to use SwiftUI.

Comment: I did the following in my mainView but it is displaying "No city" but in CityLocaionView  the city displayed as "San Fransciso" // import SwiftUI

struct mainView: View {

Comment: import SwiftUI

struct mainView: View {
    @State var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is a Main View")
        Text(text)
    }
}


#if DEBUG
struct mainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        mainView(text: "")
    }
}
#endif

Comment: To track down your problems, 
can you run my code with `MainView` on a **real device**, not in `Previews`.
Since you don't show the code for `CityLocationView2Config` and `Location`, 
it is difficult to understand what you are doing. Show that code and show how it is called in your App.
PS, use the general conventions of, names of types and protocols are UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase.